# is it possible to OpenVPN connection UDP through SSH tunnel?

Tags: linux, openvpn, tcp, ssh-tunnel, udp

Hi i search a lot on the Internet, especially in this site and read more post and articles about using OpenVPN connection through SSH tunnel but all tutorials about using TCP protocol to do that. in our internet network (Some countries block the internet and most of internet call applications) we can use only SSH tunneling that's ok with tcp connections but internet call applications like whatsapp ,instagram,telegram call doesn't work anymore so i need to use OpenVPN connection through SSH tunnel with UDP protocol (that doesn't work for me) or anyway or any protocol that use UDP connections and also works on smart phones but i need all this apps behind on ssh tunnel because other protocols blocked very soon like v2ray

Comment: SSH can not tunnel UDP

Answer (score 0):

SSH can not tunnel UDP. If you want to run OpenVPN through SSH, you are required to use TCP.

However, in some cases you probably don't need OpenVPN if you have SSH working. First of all, OpenSSH has the capability to do VPN on its own. Citing `man ssh`:

```
SSH-BASED VIRTUAL PRIVATE NETWORKS
     ssh contains support for Virtual Private Network (VPN) tunnelling
     using the tun(4) network pseudo-device, allowing two networks to be 
     joined securely.  The sshd_config(5) configuration option PermitTunnel 
     controls whether the server supports this, and at what level (layer 2 
     or 3 traffic).

     The following example would connect client network 10.0.50.0/24 with 
     remote network 10.0.99.0/24 using a point-to-point connection from 
     10.1.1.1 to 10.1.1.2, provided that the SSH server running on the 
     gateway to the remote network, at 192.168.1.15, allows it.

     On the client:

           # ssh -f -w 0:1 192.168.1.15 true
           # ifconfig tun0 10.1.1.1 10.1.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.252
           # route add 10.0.99.0/24 10.1.1.2

     On the server:

           # ifconfig tun1 10.1.1.2 10.1.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.252
           # route add 10.0.50.0/24 10.1.1.1

     Client access may be more finely tuned via the /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
     file (see below) and the PermitRootLogin server option.  The following 
     entry would permit connections on tun(4) device 1 from user “jane” and 
     on tun device 2 from user “john”, if PermitRootLogin is set to 
     “forced-commands-only”:

       tunnel="1",command="sh /etc/netstart tun1" ssh-rsa ... jane
       tunnel="2",command="sh /etc/netstart tun2" ssh-rsa ... john

     Since an SSH-based setup entails a fair amount of overhead, it may be 
     more suited to temporary setups, such as for wireless VPNs.  More 
     permanent VPNs are better provided by tools such as ipsecctl(8) and 
     isakmpd(8).
```

Modern Linux distributions don't include obsolete `ifconfig` and `route` programs by default anymore, better use more modern `ip` utility to do the same thing:

```
ip addr add 10.1.1.1 peer 10.1.1.2 dev tun0
ip route add 10.0.99.0/24 via 10.1.1.2
```

and so on.

Secondly, OpenSSH client (included as a feature in recent Windows versions too) contains a SOCKS proxy interface. It even doesn't require any special support on the SSH server side besides the usual TCP tunneling. From `man ssh`:

```
     -D [bind_address:]port
             Specifies a local “dynamic” application-level port forwarding.  
             This works by allocating a socket to listen to port on the 
             local side, optionally bound to the specified bind_address.  
             Whenever a connection is made to this port, the connection is 
             forwarded over the secure channel, and the application protocol 
             is then used to determine where to connect to from the remote 
             machine.  Currently the SOCKS4 and SOCKS5 protocols are 
             supported, and ssh will act as a SOCKS server.  Only root can 
             forward privileged ports.  Dynamic port forwardings can also be 
             specified in the configuration file.

             IPv6 addresses can be specified by enclosing the address in 
             square brackets.  Only the superuser can forward privileged 
             ports.  By default, the local port is bound in accordance with 
             the GatewayPorts setting.  However, an explicit bind_address 
             may be used to bind the connection to a specific address.  The 
             bind_address of “localhost” indicates that the listening port
             be bound for local use only, while an empty address or ‘*’ 
             indicates that the port should be available from all  interfaces.
```

So you run e.g. `ssh -D 12345 user@server`, and configure your browser (or other program) to use SOCKS proxy at `localhost:12345`; it will appear in the Internet as connecting from `server`. If some program only supports HTTP proxies and does not support SOCKS, you can use `proxify` HTTP proxy to chain HTTP proxy to this SSH-provided SOCKS.

Comment: I use it same thing but my problem is internet calls on applications like Telegram or WhatsApp and in my search, they use UDP protocols so ssh tunneling doesn't work here

Comment: @minttux surely you can run a TCP Openvpn tunnel across an ssh tunnel and the udp should be able to traverse that - albeit not very efficiently?

Comment: Very inefficiently. And my point was that you don't need OpenVPN, you can run UDP through *SSH VPN*. It is fully capable VPN, it will tunnel anything. One less encapsulation, better efficiency. Albeit still bad.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Your Description is about that? if not can you give me a link or clue

Comment: Did you try to read first half of my answer? It has both the description of SSH VPN and the reference.